# Django rest api root view showing links of another app

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a projects which has two apps in it, app1, app2 both having,

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
```

in its url.py, both of them as a standalone app ie if other app router is commented, will show correct default root API of all links. But when launching both of them, I am having an issue of apps2 api links coming in app1, by overwriting similar links of app1 which is similar in terms of serilizer, viewset and model name[image: API default view]

This is my projects **urls.py** file

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('app1/', include('app1.urls'),name='oc_url'),
    path('app2/', include('app2.urls'),name='pc_url'),
    
]
```

App1 urls.py is

```
from app1.views import ActiveUsersViewSet,ProjectsViewSet,TestsExecutedViewSet,TestRunsViewSet,DefectsViewSet,FeaturesViewSet
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'activeusers', ActiveUsersViewSet)
router.register(r'projects', ProjectsViewSet)
router.register(r'testsexecuted', TestsExecutedViewSet)
router.register(r'testruns', TestRunsViewSet)
router.register(r'defects', DefectsViewSet)
router.register(r'features', FeaturesViewSet)
```

App2 urls.py

```
from app2.views import ActiveUsersViewSet,ProjectsViewSet,SessionsHistoryViewSet
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'activeusers', ActiveUsersViewSet)
router.register(r'projects', ProjectsViewSet)
router.register(r'sessionshistory', SessionsHistoryViewSet)
```

The issue is coming with api which is related to models which has same name in both apps.
Is it because I have same models with same name in both apps? Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: having the same issue here. two different apps with same model names. drf seems to generate the wrong urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around, it looks like the issue is conflicting `url_name`s. In your case, you will have conflicting `url_names` for your `ActiveUsersViewset`s, and `ProjectsViewSet`s.

You can get around this by specifying a [`base_name`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage). This will ensure that all of your `url_name`s are unique:

**app1/urls.py**

```
from app1.views import ActiveUsersViewSet,ProjectsViewSet,TestsExecutedViewSet,TestRunsViewSet,DefectsViewSet,FeaturesViewSet
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'activeusers', ActiveUsersViewSet, "app1/activeusers")
router.register(r'projects', ProjectsViewSet, "app1/projects")
router.register(r'testsexecuted', TestsExecutedViewSet, "app1/testsexecuted")
router.register(r'testruns', TestRunsViewSet, "app1/testruns")
router.register(r'defects', DefectsViewSet, "app1/defects")
router.register(r'features', FeaturesViewSet, "app1/features")
```

**app2/urls.py**

```
from app2.views import ActiveUsersViewSet,ProjectsViewSet,SessionsHistoryViewSet
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'activeusers', ActiveUsersViewSet, "app2/activeusers")
router.register(r'projects', ProjectsViewSet, "app2/projects")
router.register(r'sessionshistory', SessionsHistoryViewSet, "app2/sessionhistory")
```